# \printbibliography only with \citetitle occurrences

Tags: biblatex, subdividing, sorting, back-referencing

I want to print two bibliographies:

- first, a classic bibliography with documents I cited in my text, I always use `\footcite{}`
- and a second who references only occurrences `\citetitle{}`

Actually, I mark my references of pictures, artworks, musical works, performances, art exhibitions, museum exhibitions or architectural works in my text with `\citetitle{}`. I don't need use `\footcite{}` for that. I reserved to verbal works: books, articles, podcasts, etc. But I want they be referenced in another final references section, named here "Œuvres & monuments", possibly classifed by type of document.

Classify by type of document is a section named "film" with all my films referenced, another one named "paintings" with all my paintings, "photographies" etc. Types appears in my '.bib' with '@misc' for exemple. (Of course, other problem is the translation from my reference management software : `@film` becomes `@electronic` or here `@painting` -> `@misc`…)

So, it's between bibliography & index: I have a lot of entries referenced (author, title, date…) like in a bibliography but I want to facilitate indexing like in an index. My solution is using `[backref=true]`… Well, subsidiary question: is it possible using `backref` in a bibliography and not in another ?

I resume my questions:

- `\printbibliography` with only `\citetitle` references ?
- classify my first bibliography by `sorting=nyvt` & my second by type (`@image`,`@movie`…) ?
- using `backref` in a bibliography and not in another ?

An idea ? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ticomp,sorting=nyvt,isbn=false,doi=false,backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
… some \footnote{MerleauPonty:1985wh}, some \citetitle{Burton:1982td,Leradeaudelamedu:1819wn,Persepolis:2007wt} & some words indexed.

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Bibliographie},backref=false]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Œuvres & monuments},backref=true]
\printindex[nam]
\printindex[loc]

\end{document}
```

My `biblio.bib`

```
@electronic{Burton:1982td,
author = {Burton, Tim},
title = {{Vincent}},
year = {1982},
language = {anglais}}

@book{MerleauPonty:1985wh,
author = {Merleau-Ponty, Maurice and Lefort, Claude},
title = {{L'{\OE}il et l'Esprit}},
publisher = {Gallimard},
year = {1985},
series = {Folio. Essais},
address = {Paris},
language = {fran{\c c}ais}}

@electronic{Persepolis:2007wt,
author = {Satrapi, Marjane and Paronnaud, Vincent},
title = {{Persepolis}},
year = {2007},
language = {fran{\c c}ais}}

@misc{Leradeaudelamedu:1819wn,
title = {{Le radeau de la m{\'e}duse}},
author = {G{\'e}ricault, Th{\'e}odore},
year = {1819},
read = {Yes}}
```

Comment: Please post code which will **compile**. That code won't. I don't have `Biblio.bib`, for example. Moreover, it would demonstrate the problem anyway because `\footnote{...}` is not a citation on two grounds (it is just a footnote and there is no key) and `\citetitle{...}` is not a citation on one ground (it is a citation command but there's still no key). Etc. etc. Also, you don't say if *your* version of the code works or, if not, what is wrong. (And I can't tell because I don't have compilable code.) I am guessing the answers to your questions are: No*3, Yes*2. (Maybe redefine commands?)

Comment: Could you please expand on what you mean by "second [bibliography is to be ordered] by type".

Comment: One can specify `sorting` in `\printbibliography`. So there is no problem in using `\printbibliography[title={Bibliographie},sorting=nyvt]` and `\printbibliography[title={Œuvres & monuments},sorting=nty]` for example.

Comment: Hi @cfr Thank you for yours reactions, I'll republished my post to be more precise. Sorry for my english & the time of answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can redefine `\citetitle` to add all entries cited via `\citetitle` to a bibliography category `oeuvres`.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{oeuvres}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{oeuvres}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}%
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

The first bibliography can then ignore `oeuvres`, while the second only includes `oeuvres`.

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Bibliographie},notcategory=oeuvres]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Œuvres \& monuments},category=oeuvres]
```

To get rid of the page references in the first bibliography, we use

```
\AtNextBibliography{\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}}
```

right before the first `\printbibliography`.
Globally, `backref` is enabled, but the macro printing the backreferences is temporarily disabled in the first bibliography.

I'm not sure about your sorting requests, but is no problem to specify the sorting in the `\printbibliography` command:

```
\printbibliography[sorting=nyt, heading=subbibliography, title={Bibliographie}, notcategory=oeuvres]
\printbibliography[sorting=ynt, heading=subbibliography, title={Œuvres \& monuments}, category=oeuvres]
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ticomp,isbn=false,doi=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{oeuvres}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{oeuvres}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}%
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
some \footcite{cicero,gillies}, some \citetitle{wilde,coleridge} \& some words indexed.

\printbibheading
\AtNextBibliography{\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Bibliographie},notcategory=oeuvres,sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Œuvres \& monuments},category=oeuvres,sorting=ynt]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To sort the bibliography by type we need to define a new sorting scheme: `tnyvt`.
Unfortunately,

```
\sort{
  \field{entrytype}
}
```

did not work for me, so we use a workaround: The entrytype is parked in the temporary field `usera` which is used for sorting.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=usera, origentrytype]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{tnyvt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{usera}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I try all of that, & if I saw any problem I return. Thank you su much.

Comment: Hello @moewe ! I precise my answer about types in the question. So I want my second references section to be classified by type, for exemple here : first all movies (`@film` or `@electronic`) second all paintings (`@painting` or here `@misc`). If you have an idea. May be I'll open a new question. Thanks

Comment: @Zouib Have a look at the edited answer. Maybe this helps you.